# Javascript jQuery How to load default image if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to load the default image if the user's one didn't exist. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
$('#avatar').load(function(){
    // ... loaded  
}).error(function(){
    // ... not loaded
    $(this).attr('src','/images2/no-avatar2.png');
});
```

Anyone know how I could do this?

Someone uses this:

```
function loadDefault(f, ff) {
img = document.getElementById(f);
if(!img.complete) {
    img.src = ff;
}
if(typeof(img.naturalWidth) != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth == 0) {
    img.src = ff;
}
}

function init() {
setTimeout("loadDefault('side_avatar', '/images/default/avatar_player_profile.gif')", 100);
setTimeout("imageResize(740)", 100);
tooltip = new ToolTip();
tooltip.init('hoverBox', 'loading...');

}
```

How could I use something like this?

Comment: Once I did the same thing and it worked. I used plain JS, though. Are you sure, `load` and `error` from `jQuery` are equivalent for that? Also you need to set that callbacks **before** image loading would be finished.

Comment: I can only code PHP and I got this from someone's tutorial, so I would know how to do it.

Comment: do it with php..much easier, check field value , if none set your default one

Comment: "it didnt work" "someone uses" "something like" _Precision_, sir! Learn it!

Comment: I dont need to. I never use things like this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing your load url as the first parameter of the `load()` function. Also, without seeing your HTML, I'll assume `#avatar` is an `img` tag the way you are using it in the error function.  I don't think you can load HTML into an `img` so you may be better off structuring your html and js like so:

HTML Example:

```
<div id="avatarDiv">
  <img id="avatar" src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

JS Example:

```
$('#avatarDiv').load('avatar.php', function() {
  // ... loaded
}).error(function() {
  // ... not loaded
  $('img#avatar').attr('src','/images2/no-avatar2.png');
});
```

Then just make sure your `avatar.php` file returns the full html of the image object:

```
<img id="avatar" src="successful-avatar.jpg" alt="" />
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I dont want to use avatar.php though.

Comment: what do you want to use?  You have to pass in a file/resource url, its required.  What else could you possibly be loading?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
$.get("get-avatar.php", function(response) {
    $("#avatar").attr('src', response);
}).error(function(response) {
    $(this).attr('src', '/images2/no-avatar2.png');
})
```

as long as avatar.php returns a http error message if the image doesn't exist.

Comment: get-avatar.php. I dont want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

This routine uses ajax to see if the image file exists:

**HTML:**

```
<img id='avatar' src='/images2/avatar2find.png' alt='No Image Available'></img>
```

**Script:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var $img = $('#avatar');
  $.ajax({
    url: $img.attr('src'),
    type: 'get',
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
      $img.attr('src', '/images2/no-avatar2.png');
      }
    },
    error:
      function() {
        // do something?
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.6 or higher?

Comment: You're right. The first solution worked in IE, but not Chrome. The new solution above should be compatible with all Browsers and will also degrade gracefully when JavaScript is not enabled.

Comment: Also Im not looking for a file, its a URL